# PHP search array for a value between two numbers

Tags: php, arrays

What's the best way of searching an array for a number within a range? e.g. between 1000 and 1500.

```
<?php
$numbers = array(1105,2140,3170);

$needle = **value between 1000 and 1500**;

if (in_array($needle, $numbers)) {
  echo "Match found";
} else {
  echo "Match not found";
}
?>
```

In this case, this would return 'Match found' as 1105 is between 1000 and 1500.

Can I set a range for the `$needle` variable?

Comment: in_array looks incorrect.

Comment: You want every value in array check if it is between 1000 and 1500?

Comment: Do you want to know what the matches _are_ or just that at least one match _exists_?

Comment: *best* in what way?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a range and use it as the "needle", but not using `in_array`.  You can create a range and compute the intersection of the numbers array. To just check for any match:

```
$numbers = array(1105, 2140, 3170);
$needle  = range(1000, 1500);

if (array_intersect($numbers, $needle)) {
  echo "Match found";
} else {
  echo "Match not found";
}
```

Or to get the possible match(es):

```
$numbers = array(1105, 2140, 3170);
$needle  = range(1000, 1500);
$result  = array_intersect($numbers, $needle);
```

Or you can filter out the ones not in the range:

```
$numbers = array(1105, 2140, 3170);
$min = 1000;
$max = 1500;
$result  = array_filter($numbers, function($v) use($min, $max) {
                                     return $v >= $min && $v <= $max;
                                 });
```

You will get an empty array if there are no matches in either case.  Also, you don't state what you want if there is more than one, but you'll get an array in either case so you could use `current` for one or `min` and/or `max` instead:

```
$one = current(array_intersect($numbers, $needle));
$min = min(array_intersect($numbers, $needle));
$max = max(array_intersect($numbers, $needle));
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option did the trick. I hadn't come across array_intersect before.

Answer (score 2):

*What's the best way of searching an array for a number within a range*. To answer this, there are 2 approaches as mentioned below:

**Approach #1:**

You can use a simple foreach loop to get all values from your unordered data which lie in the range.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1105,2140,3170);

$start = 1000;
$end = 1500;

$result = [];

foreach($numbers as $num){
    if($num >= $start && $num <= $end) $result[] = $num;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/D1Rfu

**Approach #2:(recommended for future lookups)**

You can sort your data and use [`binary search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to get the starting point of where your numbers start falling in the range of `start` and `end` for ***faster lookups***. Then, you can just look from that index till the index you get a higher number or reach the end of the array.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1105,2140,3170,1000,1500,1501);

$start = 1000;
$end  = 1500;
$start_index = -1;

sort($numbers);

$low = 0; $high = count($numbers) - 1;

while($low <= $high){
    $mid = intval(($low + $high) / 2);
    if($numbers[$mid] > $end){
        $high = $mid - 1;
    }else if($numbers[$mid] < $start){
        $low = $mid + 1;
    }else{
        $start_index = $mid;
        $high = $mid - 1;
    }
}

$result = [];
for($i = $start_index; $i < count($numbers); ++$i){
    if($numbers[$i] > $end) break;
    $result[] = $numbers[$i];
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/WcgXv

Comment: @revo Thanks. Yes, first approach is the best, however if there are frequent lookups for different ranges, approach 2 is better.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in function for these purpose. So create a function that will help you.

```
function searchOnRange(array $stack, $min=0, $max=0)
{
    // Loop through each value of array
    foreach($stack as $value){
        // CHeck value is between the given range
        if(($value >= $min) && ($value <= $max)){
            echo "Match found - ".$value;
        } else {
            echo "Match not found - ".$value;
        }
    }
}

$numbers = array(1105,2140,3170);
searchOnRange($numbers, 1000, 1500);
```